# Rails 3 - how to make a bit complicated query to database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I am trying to make a statement from database, when I would like to get the data from database by the value from session and also by the values, that are stored in the another table.

I have now something like this:

```
@data = Data.where("author = ?", session[:user_id]).order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(5)
```

From this query I will get the data from user **session[:user_id]** and now I would like to get all lines from the table **B**, where **id=session[:user_id]**, something like this:

```
@bleh = B.where("author = ?", session[:user_id])
```

And the data from this query to use into model **Data**, but I don't know how yet... I am newbie in RoR, could you anyone help me, please?

Thank you

Comment: solved, but I am not sure, if the way is the best: `bla = Array.new
    @aaa = B.where("col = ?", session[:user_id])
    for aa in @aaa
      bla= " OR author=" + aa.column.to_s
    end`

Comment: having real columns and models names would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

mmm I'm not sure if I understand everything right however it seems that you want sth like

```
values = B.where( "column = ?", session[:user_id] ).map(&:column)
data = Data.where( :author => values )
```